# How to display several new options (creatable) for only one entry?

Tags: react-select

I am using `<Select.Creatable>` in a form to choose a delay. I'd like the user can write e.g. **45** and the options available are : **45 minuts** and **45 hours**. If **45 minuts** is already in the options list, only **45 hours** would appear as achoice.
With the `optionComponent` attribute I can define a component who can display the 2 options but I'm not sure this is the good way...

Need help ! Thanks